# A probability question: a building and an elevator.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that 7 people waiting for an elevator in a building with 14 flours.
Q: What is the probability that every person get out in different flour?

My attempt:

There is $14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot \ldots \cdot 7$ ways to divide these 7 people in different flours. But what the total possibilities?

Thanks!

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: None whatsoever, they are all headed to the same party on the 5th floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I apologize for the wrong answer here. I give the correct solution now:
$$
P(S)=\frac{13!}{7!14^6}
$$
This is because the first person can go to any floor, and the other 6 can select any floor apart from the one already taken, the probability of which is $\frac{14-(k-1)}{14}$.

Comment: Where does your $\dfrac89$ come from?  Specifically, where does the '9' there come from?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki:  I believe that the calculation that was carried out was $\frac{14}{14}\times \frac{13}{14}\times \frac{12}{13}\times \frac{11}{12}\times   ... \frac{8}{9}$ which produces the stated result.  I believe the result is incorrect.

Comment: Apologies, I see now my solution is incorrect. Given the acceptance and that the other answer is correct, do you think I should correct it or delete whatsoever?

Answer (score 1):

The 7 people are waiting **on** one of the floors (probably the main floor), leaving 13 floors for them to possibly go to on the elevator.

The first person can go to any of the 13 possibilities, the second to any of the remaining  12, the third to any of the remaining 11, and so on...

So, the desired probability P is:$$P=\frac{13}{13}\times \frac{12}{13}\times \frac{11}{13}\times \frac{10}{13}\times \frac{9}{13}\times \frac{8}{13}\times \frac{7}{13}$$

If we assume 14 floors and another location to await an elevator as in the comment of Andre below, the desired probability P is:$$P=\frac{14}{14}\times \frac{13}{14}\times \frac{12}{14}\times \frac{11}{14}\times \frac{10}{14}\times \frac{9}{14}\times \frac{8}{14}$$

Comment: They could be in the basement parking garage.

Comment: @Andre  Yes, that could very well be one of the floors... :)